# How create different apps for different logins with shinymanager package? R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)
inactivity <- "function idleTimer() {
var t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);
window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches mouse clicks
window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling
window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions
function logout() {
window.close();  //close the window
}
function resetTimer() {
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(logout, 120000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
}
}
idleTimer();"

credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("1", "fanny", "victor", "benoit"),
  password = c("1", "azerty", "12345", "azerty"),
  # comment = c("alsace", "auvergne", "bretagne"), %>% 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
ui <- secure_app(head_auth = tags$script(inactivity),
  
# classic ui logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  # classic server logic
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is a way to identify different users with shinymanager package? Something like this:

```r
if(user=="fanny"){
#one dashboard
}
if(user=="benoit"){
#another dashboard
}
```

My intention is to create different apps depending on who is logged in... if the user is Benny, show one app if it's Benoit, show another, if it's Victor, show another.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr would provide an info field; quote: "the value of info then becomes the row of data associated with that user which can be used in the main to control content based on user permission variables etc." - maybe you could use that?

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar answer provided in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806386/how-to-disable-a-shiny-feature-based-on-shinymanager-credentials). Solution is to put credentials into reactive values. You could use the creds_reactive()$user to access which user is currently logged in and define a custom app